# T-SQL SELECT STATEMENT AS A VARIABLE AND PUT RESULT TO ANOTHER VARIABLE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is the last part of my function:

```
 SET @query = (N'SELECT [' +@outColumn+'] FROM [Production].[dbo].[v_time] WHERE textile LIKE '''+@outTextile+'''')
```

I tried like this: (also I tried with 'exec sp_executesql(@query)' and it doesn't work)

```
 SET @output = (@query)
 RETURN @output
```

And as result I get is the exact SQL query I wanted. But, how to RUN (execute) @query and its result (in this case it is a decimal number) put in variable @output and return??

Comment: Building dynamic sql is not recommended as it opens you up to Sql injection attacks. Make sure you are properly sanitizing your inputs!

Answer (score 3):

Try something like.....

```
Declare @query     NVarchar(MAX)
      , @outColumn SYSNAME
      , @Out       DECIMAL(10,2)

SET @query =  N' SELECT TOP 1 @Out = ' +QUOTENAME(@outColumn) 
           +  N' FROM [Production].[dbo].[v_time] '
           +  N' WHERE textile LIKE ''%'' + @outTextile + ''%'''

 Exec sp_executesql @query
                   ,N'@outTextile VARCHAR(50) , @Out DECIMAL(10,2) OUTPUT'
                   ,@outTextile
                   ,@Out OUTPUT
```

Comment: it doesn't allow me to run SP inside of the function.

Comment: You cannot use Dynamic sql/ or even execute any stored procedure inside a user-defined function this is a limitation no way around.

Comment: I agree with @M.Alie, I would take his approach and wrap it in a parameterized procedure instead of a function.